# unable to randomize submissions coming from reddit

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, praw

i am trying to make my discord bot grab images from the r/memes subreddit.

here is my code the interfaces with the reddit api

```
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('memes')
hot_python = subreddit.hot(limit=100)

for submission in hot_python:
    print(submission.title)

async def meme():
    memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied)
```

here is my code to send the selected post

```
elif message.content == "!meme":
        channel = message.channel
        await message.channel.send(submission.url)
```

when ever i run the command it send the same meme over and over instead of choosing a random one.
any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You're creating a new generator at every iteration of your `for i in range(0, post_to_pick):` loop so naturally, you'll always get the first item that statisfies the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a random post from a subreddit is a Reddit feature which [PRAW supports](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.random).

Here's a function that gets a random post from a specified subreddit:

```
def random_post(subreddit):
    return reddit.subreddit(subreddit).random()
```

And if you want the post not to be stickied, use this:

```
def random_nonsticky_post(subreddit):
    while True:
        post = reddit.subreddit(subreddit).random()
        if not post.stickied:
            return post
```

As discussed in [your followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216514/unable-to-get-a-random-post-from-some-subreddits-with-praw), it's important to note that some subreddits do not permit getting a random post.

Comment: i dont know what im doing wrong, but i put your function and replaced               
`await message.channel.send(submission.url)` with                                           
`await message.channel.send(post.title)` and it gives me the error `NameError: name 'post' is not defined`

Comment: @anytarsier67 you should call my function by doing `submission = random_post('memes')` and then do `await message.channel.send(submission.url)`. (in other words, what name are you giving to the return value of my function?)