# Unable to get a random post from some subreddits with PRAW

Tags: python-3.x, praw

i am trying to make a disord bot send images from reddit with this code (just to grab not to send)

```
def random_post(subreddit):
while True:
    post = reddit.subreddit(subreddit).random()
    if not post.stickied:
        return post
```

it normally works fine but every once in a while i get this error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stickied'
```

it only happens with certain subreddits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is a known issue on Reddit's end.

Some subreddits will refuse to give you a random submission. See [praw-dev/praw#885](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/885) on GitHub.

On that issue, I [went in depth](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/885#issuecomment-359691252) about the cause. My findings were: **When a subreddit's moderators uncheck the "allow this subreddit to be exposed to users in /r/all, /r/popular, default, and trending lists" checkbox in their subreddit settings, it prevents the subreddit from being able to provide a random submission.** For example, at the time of this writing, https://reddit.com/r/wallpapers/random just redirects to https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers/ instead of to some submission.

In my personal opinion, this is a Reddit bug caused by confusion between `/r/random` (which redirects to a random subreddit) and `/r/{subreddit}/random` (which redirects to a random submission within a subreddit). As it stands, the checkbox affects both settings, when in my view it only makes sense for it to affect `/r/random`.

In the same GitHub issue, a Reddit developer chimed in to confirm that ["the two behaviors are connected"](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/885#issuecomment-360505875) and said that this behavior ["isn't a bug *per se*."](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/885#issuecomment-360007015) That was over two years ago and nothing has changed on Reddit's end since.

---

## So what does this mean for you?

Unfortunately there's no good way to get around this. As you've discovered, for some subreddits, `subreddit.random()` returns `None`. This is [noted in the documentation of the method](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.random). In your code, you should check that `post` is not `None`. In the case that it is `None`, it's up to you how to handle that. You could just return `None`, or perhaps you could use an alternate method to get a random submission, such as (for instance) getting 25 submissions from the hot listing and using [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to select one.